# How to hide or disable 'slug' field in django admin?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I'd like to disable (preferred) or hide 'slug' field in django admin page. I found bug from django source code "[prepopulated_fields crashes with get_readonly_fields](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13618)" but it actually didn't solve the problem.

I'm using django 1.5.5

### Example basic situation:

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
...
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    readonly_fields = ('slug',)
...
```

#### The exception

```
KeyError at /admin/blog/post/2/
u"Key 'slug' not found in Form"

  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:      http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/post/2/
  Django Version:   1.5.5
  Exception Type:   KeyError
  Exception Value:  u"Key 'slug' not found in Form"
  Exception Location:   /home/XXXXXX/django_projects/virtualenvs/myenv27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in __getitem__, line 111
  Python Executable:    /home/XXXXXX/django_projects/virtualenvs/myenv27/bin/python
  Python Version:   2.7.3
```

This is probably very simple problem but I couldn't find working solution. Maybe someone knows good solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to make it readonly if you're editing?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to turn the slug field off when editing post in django admin.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but should be close:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.instance:
            self.prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}


    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = []
        if obj:
            fields += ['slug']

        return fields
```